# Using group_concat with where in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm having a hard time performing a query in MySQL where I can filter some results.

My table structure looks like this:

```
Client
+--------------------+
| id      |  name    |
+--------------------+
| 1       | client1  |
| 2       | client2  |
| 3       | client3  |
| 4       | client4  |
+--------------------+

Module
+--------------------+
| id      |  name    |
+--------------------+
| 1       | module1  |
| 2       | module2  |
| 3       | module3  |
| 4       | module4  |
+--------------------+

Client_Module
+-------------------------+
| client_id  | module_id  |
+-------------------------+
| 1          | 2          |
| 1          | 3          |
| 2          | 1          |
| 2          | 2          |
| 2          | 4          |
| 3          | 4          |
| 4          | 1          |
| 4          | 2          |
| 4          | 3          |
| 4          | 4          |
+-------------------------+
```

And my query was built as follows:

```
SELECT     client.id, client.name, GROUP_CONCAT(module.id) AS modules
FROM       client
LEFT JOIN  client_module ON client_module.client_id = client.id
LEFT JOIN  module ON module.id = client_module.module_id
WHERE      client_module.module_id = 4 AND client_module.module_id = 3
group by client.id
```

The idea of the query is that it brings me all clients that only have module 3 and 4. If my query there was correct, the result that should appear would be only client 4, only it has modules 3 and 4.

If I use the WHERE client_module.module_id IN (3,4) it shows a result where all values contain 3 or 4. In this case the filter needs to be specific for who contains the same module.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c4889/57)

I put the example in SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a direct modification from your current query is by using `HAVING` and `FIND_IN_SET` like this:

```
SELECT     client.id, client.name, GROUP_CONCAT(module.id) AS modules
FROM       client
LEFT JOIN  client_module ON client_module.client_id = client.id
LEFT JOIN  module ON module.id = client_module.module_id
group by client.id, client.name
HAVING FIND_IN_SET(3,modules)+FIND_IN_SET(4,modules) > 1;
```

The `FIND_IN_SET` will look for the value location in the `GROUP_CONCAT()` string if exists. To confirm the returned value, let's make the query as subquery and run the `FIND_IN_SET` function in `SELECT`:

```
SELECT *,
      FIND_IN_SET(3,modules),FIND_IN_SET(4,modules)
FROM
(SELECT     client.id, client.name, GROUP_CONCAT(module.id) AS modules
FROM       client
LEFT JOIN  client_module ON client_module.client_id = client.id
LEFT JOIN  module ON module.id = client_module.module_id
group by client.id, client.name) v;

+----+---------+---------+------------------------+------------------------+
| id | name    | modules | FIND_IN_SET(3,modules) | FIND_IN_SET(4,modules) |
+----+---------+---------+------------------------+------------------------+
| 1  | client1 | 3,2     |                      1 |                      0 |
| 2  | client2 | 4,2,1   |                      0 |                      1 |
| 3  | client3 | 4       |                      0 |                      1 |
| 4  | client4 | 4,3,2,1 |                      2 |                      1 |
+----+---------+---------+------------------------+------------------------+
```

As you can see the location of the searched value using `FIND_IN_SET` return `0` if none found and the corresponding value location if found. Which is why directly filtering
`HAVING FIND_IN_SET(3,modules)+FIND_IN_SET(4,modules) > 1` in your query can return your desired result (the result of `client_id=4` returned `3`).

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e07d492d294b92ddd8cf275b0988fec8)